# Javascript stopped working after moving html to parent site

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have seen a few questions that are similar but they didn't seem to have the answers that helped me. So, I come to you with hat in hand.

My site was working perfectly under a test URL and then when I moved all the files to the parent url, no code changed, just a simple copy and paste with all the links updating themselves, all of a sudden I get no javascript plugins working.

Everything else came over just fine, it is only the javascript that is giving me problems. When I look at the site through firebug, it doesn't seem to show any problems. I am absolutely pulling my hair out on this one.

This is the setup I have right now:

```
    <!-- /// CSS Stylesheets ////////  -->
    <link type="text/css" href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

    <!-- /// jQuery ////////  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" ></script>

    <!-- /// SelectNav ////////  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/selectnav/selectnav.min.js"></script>

    <!-- /// Imagebox ////////  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_layout/js/imagebox/imagebox.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/imagebox/jquery.imagebox.min.js"></script>

    <!-- /// FlexSlider ////////  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_layout/js/flexslider/flexslider.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>


    <!-- /// Carousel ////////  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_layout/js/carousel/carousel.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/carousel/jquery.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- /// Validity ////////  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_layout/js/validity/css.validity.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/validity/jquery.validity.js"></script>

    <!-- /// Custom JS ////////  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/plugins.js"></script>
```

Again, everything worked before the move, so I don't think that there is anything wrong with the individual javascript files themselves. If you don't see anything wrong here, then it might be the DOM? Full disclosure, I know nothing about the DOM, if anybody has a good source for learning about configuring the DOM for beginners, please do let me know.

I appreciate any time that any of you can give to this problem.

Comment: Are the JS files in the same place?

Comment: `../` references a level above the folder the file exists in. Have you tried changing the paths?

Comment: The JS files were moved with the rest of the site but they are being called correctly. I have pulled them up successfully.

Comment: j08691,  yes, I have tried changing paths by taking out the ../ and it made no difference.

Comment: Can you give us a link?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't. The client has said that they don't want their website to be found on a support site. I am very sorry about that.

Comment: When you say that you've pulled up the JS files successfully, what do you mean? How are you testing that?

Comment: The javascript files show up in tact under the URL path when I click on them through the page source in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is caused by the fact that you are using relative URLs, and perhaps your new web server setup has changed.  Have you tried going to the NET tab in Firebug to see if all of the JavaScript files load successfully (make sure you arent getting an HTTP 404 error)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I completely forgot to mention that. The URLs work perfectly and yes I am able to load the javascript files successfully.

Comment: If you go to the console tab of firebug and re-load the page, do you see any JavaScript errors at all?

Comment: When I reload the page it still doesn't show any errors, which now that I think of it is rather strange because there is always some sort of error, even if it is a small one, right?

Comment: The console typically will show messages, although they are not necessarily errors, they could be informational messages or log messages as well.  Usually a JavaScript error will show up in red.  When you go to the Script tab in firebug and click the drop-down (it may say 'inline'), do all of your files appear in the list?

Comment: Aha! No, I didn't realize it before but the flexslider javascript files don't show up in the list.

Comment: Okay, that is probably the issue, but now we need to figure out why it isnt loading properly.  Do you see the rest of the js files in that list?  Can you verify that the JavaScript file was successfully copied to the _layout\js\flexslider\ folder?

Comment: Yes the flexslider file is definitely there as I can see it and bring it up through the source code in the browser. I went to the console and it tells me that there is an error in this line -                         "/>':" < a > "+b+" < /a>",a.controlNavScaffold.append("<li>"+g+"</li > "),b++;a.controlsContainer?d(a.controlsContainer).append(a.controlNavScaffold):a.append(a.controlNavScaffold);f.controlNav.set();f.controlNav.active();a.controlNavScaffold.delegate("

Comment: It says that it is missing a colon but I don't see where and it isn't clear where. (oh, this is in the flexslider js file)

Comment: It also says that flexslider is not a function on this line, nextText: "Next" //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item                    in the plugins.js file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50796/discussion-between-mdiesel-and-aceofhearts)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're pointing to correct location. If you were in `/web_root/test/` and you just moved everything to `/web_root/`, you'll need to update the `src` attribute of all your imported scripts to reflect this change. Assuming you just moved your files up one directory, you can simply get rid of the first `../`. For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layout/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" ></script>
```

Would be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layout/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" ></script>
```

It would be helpful to know the directory structure for your site, specifically the directory you were in while testing everything, and the directory you moved everything into.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention that I have tested that the javascript files are being called correctly. I also tried getting rid of the ../ at the beginning and this made no change whatsoever.

Comment: Like I said, it would be immensely helpful to know exactly what you changed, and where, including the directory structure.

Comment: Well, the only thing that changed was moving everything as it was under a sub URL under the parent URL and the links all changed to reflect that. Other than that everything stayed exactly the same. The folder that the javascript files were under is still there, just under the parent URL instead of a sub URL.

Comment: I'm still not convinced the links are correct. Do the JS files show up in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: I was just made aware that one of my scrips is not showing up on Firebug. The flexslider javascript file doesn't show up.